# Get Data from Session["DTable"] in Next Page and Display in Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datatable

I have a DataTable in page page.aspx that is filtered. What I want to do is use that data in page2.aspx when a GetNextButton is Clicked, I stored in a session variable but I dont know how to get this values. My question is how can I get the data out of that session variable?

```
 //In page1.aspx
 DataTable newDataTable = new DataTable();
 Session["DTable"] = newDataTable;
 gvMain.DataSource = newDataTable;
 gvMain.DataBind();
```

[image]

```
  //Button in page2.aspx
  protected void btnTakeNextTicket_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Get Next transaction from Session and display in gvPage2 on page2.aspx.
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DataTable newDataTable = (DataTable)Session["DTable"];
newDataTable.Rows[0]["<ColumnName>"].ToString();
```

Comment: But how do I get the information out of that Datatable? If you look at the image I get the first transaction out of that datable

Comment: I hope you have all the data in the datatable already when you are putting it into the session on Page1.aspx.

Comment: I do. Like I said I want to get that TopRow from that DataTable

Comment: I know I can get the Data from gridview like this gvMain.Rows[0].Cells[1].Text; but how do I get it from DataTable